# Assign Contact based on City

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow

I have a use case that I am trying to solve. Not sure if there is a nice way to do this with a flow and not blow up my SOQL limits.

The org has about 40K contact records. The client would like to have a contact tagged is in our out of their geographic footprint based on the contacts city. There are over 6000 possible city values.

If I create a FootPrint Object would a Flow work to loop through the contact city, compare it to the collection of footprint cities and update a checkbox? Or would my SOQL explode any way I tried to do this?  Once the data is set then the flow would only need to run if the field is changed.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Flow Bulkification in Transactions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_bulkification.htm), a flow should work just fine for your purposes. You wouldn't bulk load all of the footprints into memory at once. You'd construct a list of cities you need, query for those cities, then assign that to another variable, and do whatever DML updates you need to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help @sfdcfox. Question, I built another flow that counts the number of tasks a contact has with certain text in the subject. If I do an upload and don't turn my batch size way down. I will fail for exceeding SOQL limits. I don't understand why these are different.

Comment: @BrooksJohnson It depends on the design of the flow. I suggest you read the documentation carefully; bulkification only works if you're using the same flow on multiple records, *and* they run in to the same interview element. It sounds like your flow isn't designed to run bulkified, but without seeing it, I can't give specific advice. You might want to ask a new question that includes an image of your flow and how you can optimize it.